# How can I update Customer metadata in stripe? [.NET]

Tags: stripe.net

In stripe.net documentation, I could only find how to update the customer. I'm not sure if I could update a certain metadata of a customer this way.

Anywhere in documentation I can study from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that overriding the meta with original dictionary items with changed values actually does the job.